# Hi! Im writing my thesis with overleaf and I have a problem with citing some papers in my document

Tags: overleaf

I use the \bibliographystyle{apalike} and \bibliography{ref.bib} commands for my bibliography and have a ref.bib file in wich I upload all my citations. Everything was okay and all the citations appeard in my document (with the \lcitep command) but now while I was trying to cite some new papers, a question mark appeared in my document (?). This happens only with the new citations I uploaded in my ref.bib file. If I want to cite a different paper wich I have already cited there is no problem and the citation appears correct in my document. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: It sounds like Overleaf isn't seeing the more recent references.  Try recompiling from scratch.  If that doesn't work, you may want to reach out to Overleaf.

Comment: For bibtex bibliographies, you should use `\bibliography{ref}` (no .bib after the file name)

Comment: Can you make sure that there are no other unrelated errors in your file? If there would be errors, latexmk (the tool used by overleaf to compile the document), won't create the bibliography

Comment: I'm getting this error message "Package natbib Warning: Citation `domingo_1995' on page 34 undefined on input line 9"
"You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way." although the papers citation is included in my bibliography.

Comment: is that the only error in your document (so the red error count box shows 1) ?

Comment: No it is not. But it is the only error releated to this issue

Comment: _all_ errors are related to the issue as if you have any error there is no guarantee that tex will  recover in a good enough state to write the bibliography data at the end of the document. If you have any error don't ask about any pdf output, it is not intended to be usable, ask about the _first_ reported error.

Comment: see this question yesterday https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703409/very-unexpected-overleaf-bibliography-behavior-citation-not-rendering/703414#comment1749937_703414